# integral of 2-variable function in the real plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$\displaystyle{%
\iint_{D}{{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y \over \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}1 - x^{2} - y^{2}\,\,}\,}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad D \equiv \left\lbrace\left(x,y\right)\ |\ x^{2} + 4y^{2} \leq 1\right\rbrace}$

I used cylindrical coordinates, but it didn't work $\dots$ Can you help me ?

Comment: substitute $y=\frac{1}{2}z$ first, then you are able to use cylindrical coordinates

Comment: But... how to integrate $\frac{r}{1-r^{2}cos^{2}{\theta}-\frac{1}{4}r^{2}sin^{2}{\theta}}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ in the unit disk...?

Comment: Also, $\large x^{2} + y^{2} < 1$ ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a substitution $y' = 2y$ then the integral becomes

$$I = \iint_D\frac{dx dy'}{\sqrt{4-4x^2-y'^2}},$$

over the region $D:x^2 + y'^2 = 1.$  That can be put into polar coordinates a bit easier:

$$I = \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^1 \frac{rdrd\theta}{\sqrt{4 - 4r^2\cos^2 \theta - r^2\sin^2\theta}},$$

with $r^2=x^2 + y'^2, x=r \cos \theta, y' = r \sin \theta$.

Comment: thanx... but I can't compute the last integral, which you said "easier"..

Comment: I just said that it could be put into polar coordinates easier.

Comment: I miss the line. sorry

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
?&=\int_{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ <\ 1}
{\Theta\pars{1 - x^{2} - 4y^{2}} \over \root{1 - x^{2} - y^{2}}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
=
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,\rho\,
{\Theta\pars{1 - \rho^{2} - 3\rho^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}
 \over \root{1 - \rho^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,
{\Theta\pars{1 - \rho\bracks{1 + 3\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}}
 \over \root{1 - \rho}}
=
\half\int_{0}^{2\pi}\!\!\!\dd\theta\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,
{\Theta\pars{1/\bracks{1 + 3\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}} - \rho}
 \over \root{1 - \rho}}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{1/\bracks{1 + 3\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}}
{\dd\rho \over \root{1 - \rho}}
=
\half\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\,\braces{%
-2\root{1 -{1 \over 1 + 3\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}} + 2}
\\[3mm]&=2\pi - \root{3}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
{\verts{\sin\pars{\theta}} \over \root{4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
=2\pi - 2\root{3}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{\sin\pars{\theta} \over \root{4 - 3\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=2\pi - 2\root{3}\underbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd\xi \over \root{4 - 3\xi^{2}}}}
_{\ds{2\root{3}\pi \over 9}}
=
2\pi - {4\pi \over 3} = \color{#0000FF}{\Large{2\pi \over 3}}
\end{align}